# How to change CardView size with animation?

Tags: android, material-design, android-cardview

I have a CardView in my layout and I want to make its width and height bigger with this fancy material style animation like in this [video](https://material-design.storage.googleapis.com/publish/material_v_4/material_ext_publish/0B6Okdz75tqQsZWtfWjlEQ0RTcXc/whatismaterial-materialprop-transformingmaterial-PaperShapeLinear_xhdpi_005.webm)

I tried to use something like`cardView.animate().scaleX(1.2f).scaleY(1.2f)` but it scales view with its content, but I need just change the size of CardView.

Answer (score 0):

Add a container `<RelativeLayout>`, `<FrameLayout>` or `<LinearLayout` with fixed dimensions and `layout_gravity` set to `center`, and put the contents of the card in there. This container will float in the center, keeping the dimensions you specify, no matter how big the card gets.

Comment: @Alpex, It doesn't work - After cardView.animate().scaleY() the size of the contents changes even if the content is hold by the FrameLayout with specific layout_height and layout_width.